# Sequentially execute node.js code

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, asynchronous

```
client.hydrated().then(function (client) {
   client.query({ query: x})
       .then(function logData(data) {
           console.log('results of query: ', data);
           fs.writeFileSync('notesdata.json', JSON.stringify(data))
       })
       .catch(console.error);`enter code here`
});

var xy=fs.readFileSync('notesdata.json');
```

This is a part of AWS sdk. The last line which reads the data from teh file is executed first and this function is executed afterwards. I know about call back functions but don't know how to implement it here, can i get some help.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The promises are incorrectly used. They should always be chained to provide consistent control flow and error handling:

```
   client.hydrated().then(function (client) {
      return client.query({ query: x})
   })
   .then(function logData(data) {
       console.log('results of query: ', data);
       fs.writeFileSync('notesdata.json', JSON.stringify(data))
       // no real need to read it from file because it's already available as `data`
       var xy=fs.readFileSync('notesdata.json');
   })
   .catch(console.error);
```

Comment: better use async waterfall

Comment: `better use async waterfall` - why? Promises already provide the functionality you're looking for in this scenario

Comment: @BimalKumar How is it better? I'd say it's better to use `async` funciton then because it's available in latest Node versions and provides syntactic sugar, but the actual environment is not known.

Answer (score 0):

you have two choices, first is use promise chain:

```
let initClient = () => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        client.hydrated().then(function (client) {
            resolve(client);
        }).catch(err => reject(err))
    })
}

let query = (client) => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        client.query({query: x}).then((data) => {
            fs.writeFileSync('notesdata.json', JSON.stringify(data))
            resolve()
        }).catch(err => reject(err))
    });
};

initClient().then(query).then(() => {
    var xy=fs.readFileSync('notesdata.json');
}).catch(err => {
    console.log('err: ', err);
})
```

if you use async, await the code is much easier:

```
(async () => {
    let client = await client.hydrated();
    let data = await client.query({query: x});

    console.log('data: ', data);
})().then().catch(err => {
    console.log('err: ', err);
})
```

Comment: That was helpful and i learned some new ways to do it. Thank you @Codisan

Comment: There is unnecessary `.then()` in async snippet. The code in promise snippet uses promise construction antipattern. There are already promises, no need to create another one with `new Promise`.